# CRM 2011: Plug-in - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client'

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am looking to build a fairly simple plug in that calculates the amount of "units" used & remaining.
I have two custom entites `bc_learninglicences` & `bc_llbalance`, the plug - in fires on create of `bc_llbalance` and another for update.

```
bc_llbalance: Contains
    bc_learninglicense (Look up field on bc_learninglicences / bc_name)
    bc_units (units that are used by this record)

bc_learninglicences: Contains 
    bc_name
    bc_unitsquantity (This is set to the total qty of units)
    bc_unitsused (this needs to inherit the sum of "bc_units" on "bc_llbalance")
    bc_unitsremaining ( simply bc_unitsquantity - bc_unitsused )
```

Ok so I have included the code which is obviously not finished as I have just been trying to figure out how to get `bc_unitsused` to inherit the sum... 
this code builds without error. however CRM errors:

> Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): LearningLicenses.LearningLicenses: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client, Version=5.0.9690.2165

I have a short deadline to build this as the system is due to go live soon, however I cannot move forward with this error which I don't understand...

Either help with error or code/solution will be appreciated at this point as I'm behind on the time frame for this project.

p.s I am new to developing for CRM 2011 with only a few weeks/ few projects experience.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace LearningLicenses
{
    public class LearningLicenses : IPlugin
    {

        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            try
            {

                // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
                Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext context = (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext)
                    serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext));

                //Extract the tracing service for use in debugging sandboxed plug-ins.
                ITracingService tracingService =
                    (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

                if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
                        context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
                 {

                     // Obtain the target entity from the input parmameters.
                     Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
                IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

                EntityReference a = (EntityReference)entity.Attributes["bc_learninglicense"];// ((EntityReference)targetEntity.Attributes["bc_learninglicense"]).Id;


                if (entity.LogicalName == "bc_llbalance")
                        try
                        {  

                            //fetchxml to get the sum total of estimatedvalue
                            string value_sum = string.Format(@"         
                    <fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
                        <entity name='bc_llbalance'>
                            <attribute name='bc_units' alias='units_sum' aggregate='sum' />
                               <filter type='and'>
                                <condition attribute='bc_learninglicense' operator='eq' value='{0}' uiname='' 
                               </filter>
                        </entity>
                    </fetch>", a.Id);

                            FetchExpression fetch = new FetchExpression(value_sum);
                            EntityCollection value_sum_result = service.RetrieveMultiple(fetch);
                            var TotalValue = "";
                            // decimal TotalValue = 0;
                            foreach (var c in value_sum_result.Entities)
                            {
                                TotalValue = ((string)((AliasedValue)c["value_sum"]).Value);
                            }

                            Entity llc = new Entity("bc_learninglicences");
                            llc.Id = a.Id;
                            llc.Attributes.Add("bc_unitsused", TotalValue);

                            service.Update(llc);

                        }
                        catch (FaultException ex)
                        {
                            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in the plug-in.", ex);
                        }
                }

            }
            catch (FaultException ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in the plug-in.", ex);
            }
        }
    }
 }



THE ERROR : 

Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): LearningLicenses.LearningLicenses: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client, Version=5.0.9690.2165, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220956</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): LearningLicenses.LearningLicenses: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client, Version=5.0.9690.2165, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2013-01-22T10:09:22.0275105Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>

[LearningLicenses: LearningLicenses.LearningLicenses]
[c1b35170-c563-e211-8c6d-b499bafd5e5b: LearningLicenses.LearningLicenses: Create of bc_llbalance]


</TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft.Xrm.Client is not used by CRM and so is not present in the GAC or anywhere on the CRM server, it is intended to be redistributed with any client applications that require it.

It shouldn't need to be referenced in your Plugin assembly at all, so I would remove it and see if any of your code references it. If it does it should be able to be replaced with equivalent code that doesn't use that assembly.

Comment: When i have removed the ref i get over 2000 errors within the Xrm.cs which generated using the CrmSvcUtil.exe... perhaps i have generated the wrong type of codeclass?

Comment: Your generated early bound context should end up inheriting from Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext. Another thing to consider is that your posted code doesn't seem to be using any early bound entity classes so you could just remove your generated Xrm.cs class if its not needed anywhere else.

Comment: Ok getting rid of the Xrm.cs worked fine thanks :) i had been under an impression that this always had to be included actually so glad to hear it isnt.  I am still getting errors with the actual code now, but as i said its not completed as i got held up with the Xrm.client issue. Thanks for your help. any suggestions with the logic & code to how i can achive the functions stated more efficiently? Thanks again

Comment: Why should it not be needed by the plugin? It has useful methods like `GetRelatedEntities` for example...

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways to get around this, first you may want to check that the SDK is available in the GAC, but we internally use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=17630) to bring in all dependencies that plugin requires.

Comment: You shouldn't have the SDK assemblies installed in the GAC, this can cause the CRM app to fail when updates are applied. Microsoft.Xrm.Client is not part of the CRM install, it is intended to be redistributed with any client applications that require it. It is also not required for plugins

Comment: As mentioned we included in the plugin Assembly ilmerge'd in with a couple of other dependencies we need

Comment: When i have removed the ref i get over 2000 errors within the Xrm.cs which generated using the CrmSvcUtil.exe... perhaps i have generated the wrong type of codeclass?